# %mprun keeps giving nameerror (Problem with imported modules)

Tags: python, memory, jupyter, memory-profiling

Hi I am currently trying to execute a line-by-line memory profile for one of my functions. However, whenever the function requires an imported module, the %mprun command does not work. This is a simplified example. I tried this both on jupyter, command prompt and anaconda prompt.

```
#Here I write a py file containing the function I want to profile
%%file mpruntest.py
@profile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def test(a):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5))
    return df
```

This will give me a py file called mpruntest.

```
#Here I run the mprun
from mpruntest import test
%mprun -f test test(1)
```

I keep receiving NameError stating that pd or np is not defined. I am not sure how I should go about this so that the memory profiler can work and read that the relevant modules are imported.